# Hover and position

Tags: css

My nav is showing when hovering the id circle as I wanted to be but as soon as I leave the hover the nav don't stay still.

My thoughts are that it doesn't stay because of the space I created between each other so there are not "linked" anymore.
If this is the cas, is there a solution or it's a dead end?

Here is my code.

```
    <div class="container">
<div id="menu">
<div id="circle"><a href="#"></a>
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span id="portfolio"><h2></h2></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span id="blog"><h2></h2></span></a></li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
</div>
</div>

    .container {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
position:relative;}

#invi {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
-moz-border-radius: 120px;
-webkit-border-radius: 120px;
border-radius: 120px;
border: 5px solid black;
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 45%;
}

#circle {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
-moz-border-radius: 120px;
-webkit-border-radius: 120px;
border-radius: 120px;
border: 5px solid black;
margin: 40px auto;}

nav {
display:none;
margin:0 auto;
opacity:1;
transition-property: opacity;
transition-duration: 20s}

#circle:hover nav{
display:block;
opacity:0.1;}

li{
display:inline-block;
width:1px;}

#portfolio{
float:left;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
background: white;
-moz-border-radius: 120px;
-webkit-border-radius: 120px;
border-radius: 120px;
border:solid black 5px;
margin-left:90px;
transition-property: width,height;
transition-duration:3s;}

li:hover #portfolio{
width:50px;
height:50px}

#blog{
float:left;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
background: white;
-moz-border-radius: 120px;
-webkit-border-radius: 120px;
border-radius: 120px;
border:solid black 5px;
margin-left:-150px;
transition-property: width,height;
transition-duration:3s;}

li:hover #blog{
width:50px;
height:50px}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want your nav to show and stay that way after hovering the circle?

Comment: Yes so to speak, I just want to be able to get to the nav (left and right) as soon as I leave the middle circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution without JQuery.

I just made my submenu bigger than the menu itself.

Here is the result :[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPVbyj)

```
    <div class="container">
<div id="wrap-menu">
<nav class="navigation" >
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item is">
      <a>IS</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
         <li class="submenu-item what">
           <a href="#"><span>What</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class="submenu-item seek">
           <a href="#"><span>Seek</span></a>
         </li>
      </ul> <!-- .submenu -->
    </li>
  </ul> <!-- .menu -->
 </nav>
 </div> <!-- #wrap-menu -->
 </div>



    *{
-webkit-box-sizing : border-box;
-moz-box-sizing : border-box;
    box-sizing : border-box;}

nav ul{
list-style:none;}

.container {
max-width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color:#D4EDFF;
min-height:20rem;
padding:2rem}

#wrap-menu {
margin:6rem;
padding:4rem;
background : #0Af}

.menu-item{
display:block;
width:120px;
height:120px;
border:1px black solid;
border-radius:50%;
margin:auto;}

.menu-item>a{
position:relative;
top:2.5rem;
left:3.5rem;}

.submenu{
margin:-4rem 0 0 -19.5rem;
padding-top: 5rem;
min-width: 700px;
height:200px;
background:#CEF0D9;
display:none;}

.submenu-item.what{
float:left}

.submenu-item.seek{
float:right;}

.menu-item:hover .submenu{
display:block}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use jQuery.

This is the style that does all the logic for you.

```
#circle:hover nav{
   display:block;
   opacity:0.1;
}
```

Then your JS would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#circle').mouseover(function(){
      $('#circle nav').css('display', 'block');
      $('#circle nav').css('opacity', '0.1');
   });

   //This function is called only if you LEAVE your nav
   $('#circle nav').mouseleave(function(){
      $('#circle nav').hide();
   });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alboy51/othLayp9/1/)

Comment: Wanted to avoid the JS but hey, looks like there is no other way. Thanks for that :)

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to do it but as I'm new I don't have enough reputation to be able to vote for you.
I don't forget though, as soon as I reach the 15 reputation required I'll come back to vote your answer. :/

Comment: Sorry dude, I just didn't see that bloody check mark under the arrows :/
Done :)